# Can I define a Vue JSX component within a SFC <script setup> and use it in the SFC template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I like that in React you can quickly create small components within the main component file.
Is something like that possible with Vue 3 composition API?

Something like this:

Component.vue

```
<script setup>
    const SmallComponent = <div>Test</div>
</script>
<template>
    <SmallComponent/>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) tooling?

Comment: @Bravo The project is created via vue CLI. I am not sure if its using vite or webpack. However in the project initial creation I did specify JSX support and babel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `SmallComponent` is not a component but vnode object. Vnodes can be directly rendered in render functions but not templates.

Instead, it should be [functional component](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#functional-components):

```
const SmallComponent = props => <div>Test</div>
```

In `script setup`, it's the only available option, because the syntax provides a subset of functionality and doesn't support render functions.

Comment: that won't parse in vuejs

Comment: @Bravo Why? This requires Babel JSX transform to be applied by means of `@vue/babel-plugin-jsx`, but otherwise, it's legit Vue code.

Comment: you failed to mention that plugin, you also did not mention that the script should be `<script setup lang="jsx">` - once you do add that transform, and change the script tag, then it does work

Comment: @Bravo Will it work with typescript? I use <script setup lang='ts'>.

Comment: @DaliborČarapić Should be `lang="tsx"`, and the config may be trickier because TS needs to work together with Babel on that, depends on your setup